# Adding higher resolution (1920x1080) on Ubuntu 22.04 results in a low quality image

Tags: display, display-resolution, hp

I have just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a HP Probook 450 G9 laptop.

By default the highest option fo resolution that I get in Displays is 1366x768.

I tried to add manually another resolution with `xrandr` but the resulting image is of very poor quality. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode eDP-1 1920x1080
```

And than I select the resolution.

I have a similar laptop, HP Probook 450 G8, the 1920x1080 option comes in by default, and the image is clear as it should be.

I have no problem setting the 1920x1080 resolution when I plug in an external 23 inch monitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized that 1366x768 this is the maximum supported resolution by the laptop display:

https://www.hp.com/emea_middle_east-en/products/laptops/product-details/product-specifications/2101247446

Did not pay attention to this when buying the laptop.

Comment: The model with the i7 processor can do 1920x1080 https://www.hp.com/emea_africa-en/products/laptops/product-details/product-specifications/2101279337

Comment: Your question and answer can help others to realize that it does not help to send an image with a higher resolution to a screen than it can manage, so thanks for sharing this result :-)